# Centre columns of divs

Tags: css, center, positioning

I have a page with a bunch of equal size divs that I want to fit responsively in the available space of a wrapper div.

The idea is that:
- in a large screen the divs will show in 3 columns
- in a medium size screen the divs will show in 2 columns 
- in a phone screen the divs will show in 1 column.

I'd also like the wrapper to center horizontally.

I was trying:

```
 #wrapper {margin:0 auto;}
 .column {float:left; max-width:340px; height:540px; margin:20px}
```

It works as intended except that the wrapper doesn't center, which I was trying to achieve with line 1 of css.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

EDIT:

The HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="column one">
    </div>
    <div class="column two">
    </div>
    <div class="column three">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well and read the formatting rules how to format the CSS.

Comment: post some example in jsfiddle

Comment: float + margin will not center anything. Why don't you use the column CSS and media queries to cut them down ?

Comment: The thresholds wouldn't match any other thresholds I'm using, because they would have to be based on the width of the images inside the divs.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements allow you to do so, I would suggest using a UI Framework such as [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). They have components that would achieve exactly what you are attempting to do (see their [grid system documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)).

[Example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

EDIT: Included grid documentation link & Example